# Python3. CSV. How do I write a new row to the csv file without overwriting the current row?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, csv

I am running a word guessing game. Once the word has been guessed, I want to add the details of myName, dtFullDate, attempts & wordChosen to a .csv file. This works, however if I run the game again, the previous row in the .csv gets overwritten. I've tried if statements for when a row has content to move to the next line however i was unsuccessful.

```
 outputFile = open('scoreboard.csv', 'w', newline='')
 outputWriter = csv.DictWriter(outputFile, ['Name', 'Date', 'Attempts', 'Word Chosen'])
 outputWriter.writeheader()
 outputWriter.writerow({'Name' : myName, 'Date' : dtFullDate, 'Attempts' : attempts, 'Word Chosen' : wordChosen})
 #outputWriter.writerow([myName, attemts, wordChosen, timestamp])
 outputFile.close()

 # Display the scoreboard from the scoreboard.csv file
  print(("************* scoreboard *************\n".upper()))
  outputFile = open('scoreboard.csv')
  outputDictReader = csv.DictReader(outputFile, ['Name', 'Date', 'Attempts', 'Word Chosen'])
  for row in outputDictReader:
    print([myName], [dtFullDate], [attempts], [wordChosen])
  #outputWriter.writerow([myName, dtFullDate, attempts, wordChosen])
  outputFile.close()
  break
```

Comment: The below is the output. How do I remove the '[' & "'" from the printed text? 
Also, the for loop prints the same line twice. Any ideas on how to prevent the duplicate?

`['sfdsfds'] [(12, 1, 2022)] [6] ['pizza'] ['sfdsfds'] [(12, 1, 2022)] [6] ['pizza']`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file with access mode 'a' instead of 'w', so that you append content to it.

Also, it's good practice to open files using the `with` statement, so that the file is automatically closed when the block finishes executing.

```
with open('scoreboard.csv', 'a', newline=' ') as output_file:
    # your code down to `output_file.close()` (without it) goes here
```

By the way, why do you have a `break` at the very end of your code?

Comment: @Luca, could you update the code and share the file content? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The new line now works! I removed the 'break' from the end, I originally thought it was required.

Comment: It's sorted now I was editing the comment and testing the code at the same time haha. Thanks again!

I amended `print([myName], [dtFullDate], [attempts], [wordChosen])`
to
`print(row['Name'], row['Date'], row['Attempts'], row['Word Chosen'])`